# Possible to display model pop up by click on URL instead of button?

Tags: lightning-web-components

In LWC, on button click we will display model popup. Is it possible to display model pop up by click on URL instead of button? Possible solution

```html
<template>
    <lightning-button variant="success" label="Open popup"
                        title="Open popup" onclick={showModalBox}>
    </lightning-button>

   <!-- modal start -->      
   <template if:true={isShowModal}>

            <!--
                I Used SLDS for this code
                Here is link https://www.lightningdesignsystem.com/components/modals/
            --> 

    <section role="dialog" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="modal-heading-01" aria-modal="true" aria-describedby="modal-content-id-1" class="slds-modal slds-fade-in-open">
       <div class="slds-modal__container">
        <!-- modal header start -->
          <header class="slds-modal__header">
             <button class="slds-button slds-button_icon slds-modal__close slds-button_icon-inverse" title="Close" onclick={hideModalBox}>
                <lightning-icon icon-name="utility:close"
                   alternative-text="close"
                   variant="inverse"
                   size="small" ></lightning-icon>
                <span class="slds-assistive-text">Close</span>
             </button>
             <h2 id="modal-heading-01" class="slds-text-heading_medium slds-hyphenate">Welcome in Apex Hours</h2>
          </header>
      
          <!-- modal body start -->
          <div class="slds-modal__content slds-p-around_medium" id="modal-content-id-1">
                <p>Modal/Popup in Lightning Web Component (LWC) Demo</p>
          </div>

          <!-- modal footer start-->
          <footer class="slds-modal__footer">
             <button class="slds-button slds-button_neutral" onclick={hideModalBox}>Cancel</button>
          </footer>
       
       </div>
    </section>
    <div class="slds-backdrop slds-backdrop_open"></div>
 </template>
 <!-- modal end -->

</template>
```

Answer (score 2):

If you're inside a supported Salesforce Experience, you can use [`lightning-navigation`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-navigation/documentation) `CurrentPageReference` to detect changes to the URL and respond to those changes.

```javascript
import { wire } from 'lwc';
import { CurrentPageReference } from 'lightning/navigation';
```

...

```javascript
@wire(CurrentPageReference) handleCurrentPageReference(pageReference) {
    // Change state based on pageReference contents
}
```

This works well with `NavigationMixin` from that library to maintain state, and you can use the usual `href="?key1=value1&key2=value2"` syntax with either window.location.href or in a `<a>` link, etc.

---

Outside of that, you can use window's [onhashchange](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/hashchange_event). This allows you to write links like `href="#whateverIWantHere"`.